# Append element with more than one attribute using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xpath, command-line, command, xmlstarlet

Let say I have the following xml file content:

```
<Context>
   <Parameter name="n1" value="v1" override="false"/>
   <Parameter name="n2" value="v2" override="false"/>
</Context>
```

So In my case I want to append new element **Parameter** with same attributes like this :

```
<Context>
   <Parameter name="n1" value="v1" override="false"/>
   <Parameter name="n2" value="v2" override="false"/>
   <Parameter name="n3" value="v3" override="true"/>
</Context>
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little cumbersome, but it can be done like this:

```
xmlstarlet ed --subnode "//Context" --type elem -n Parameter \
--insert  "// Context //Parameter[3]"  --type attr --name "name" --value "n3" \
--insert  "// Context //Parameter[3]" --type attr --name "value3" --value "v3" \
--insert  "// Context //Parameter[3]" --type attr --name "override" --value "false"\
myfile.xml
```

The output should be what you're looking for.

To insert a new element before `<Context>` use

```
xmlstarlet ed  -i "//Context" --type elem -n Parameter myfile.xml
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the command flexible that can add the new element before the last line of the file ?

Comment: @Stephan Do you mean insert it between `<n1>` and `<n2>`?

Comment: I mean adding it always before </Context> without giving index [index]

Comment: is that possible ?